# Show that $L_A$ is a reflection and find the line of reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, reflection

**Question:**

Let $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider the matrix:

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & \sin \phi\\
\sin \phi & - \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Prove that:

1. $L_A$ is a reflection
2. Find the axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ about which $L_A$ reflects

**My attempt:**

So I did solve this question, but only after having found what the line of reflection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is online.

The line is given by:

\begin{equation*}
    L = \{t \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi + 1\\
\sin \phi\\
\end{pmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{R}\}
\end{equation*}

So I worked backwards and said that given the orthonormal basis :

\begin{equation*}
    \beta_N = \left\{\frac{1}{c_1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
\sin \phi\\
- \cos \phi - 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
,\frac{1}{c_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi + 1\\
\sin \phi\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
\end{equation*}

(for some constants $c_1, c_2$ that make these vectors unit length), we can show that

$[L_A]_{\beta_N} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

which by definition means that $L_A$ is a reflection. And then in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the line of reflection is the span of the second vector (i.e. $L$)

However, I was only able to solve this because I knew what the line of reflection was before hand. Without this, how would one solve this question?

Initially, I thought we could use that if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, then we just need to show that det$(A) = -1$. However, nowhere does it say that the field is necessarily real.

So how would we find a suitable orthonormal basis from scratch, or otherwise solve these questions?

Thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a point, any point, in the plane (except the origin), call it $P$. Work out where $A$ takes $P$, call the answer $Q$. Then the line of reflection (assuming $A$ really is a reflection) is just the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: And $A$ will be a reflection if, and only if, it takes every point $P$ to its reflection in this line.

Comment: Thanks for that! So I assume what I would do given the points $P$ and $P'$ (where $A$ takes $P$), I would find the mid point of $P$ and $P'$, and then the line through the origin and the mid0point should be the line of reflection?

Comment: That will work, if $A$ is a reflection, unless $P'=-P$ since then the midpoint *is* the origin.